# Sharing my Android app via facebook, twitter and other social apps installed on the device

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, share

I am looking for something peculiar however useful to any app developer. I have a snippet of code in my AppName.java file however not working yet. So far it is close to what I am attempting however I want to allow the user to share the application name and download link via all the programs that appear from the action intent to twitter, facebook, etc. So I don't believe I should use emailIntent, I believe I should use sendIntent but I am thinking my entire code below is completely incorrect to do either and maybe should start over. Suggestions appreciated.

Again, I only want to share the app name, a simply message saying "I loved AppName" and the download link.

```
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Download AppName for FREE at https://market.android.com/details?id=com.CompanyName.AppName"); 
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.recommendation_subject));
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.recommendation_body));
        startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use  socialauth-android Android library for authenticating, updating status and getting contacts with social networks

[SocialAuth Android](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/) is an Android version of popular SocialAuth Java library. Now you do not need to integrate multiple SDKs if you want to integrate your application with multiple social networks. You just need to add few lines of code after integrating the SocialAuth Android library in your app.

Answer (score 0):

try to integrate facebook api so you can post any text you want on your wall

Comment: that would only be a single step. I am positive there is a code set to integrate because I have several apps on my android device that have a share feature and when I touch the menu --> share; it brings up all the social sharing apps installed, including twitter, facebook, orkut and myspace